# Caching Strategy/Design Pattern for complex queries

Tags: caching, design-patterns, redis, architecture, azure-sql-database

We have an existing API with a very simple cache-hit/cache-miss system using Redis. It supports being searched by Key. So a query that translates to the following is easily cached based on it's primary key.

`SELECT * FROM [Entities] WHERE PrimaryKeyCol = @p1`

Any subsequent requests can lookup the entity in REDIS by it's primary key or fail back to the database, and then populate the cache with that result.

We're in the process of building a new API that will allow searches by a lot more params, will return multiple entries in the results, and will be under fairly high request volume (enough so that it will impact our existing DTU utilization in SQL Azure).

Queries will be searchable by several other terms, Multiple PKs in one search, various other FK lookup columns, LIKE/CONTAINS statements on text etc...

In this scenario, are there any design patterns, or cache strategies that we could consider. Redis doesn't seem to lend itself particularly well to these type of queries. I'm considering simply hashing the query params, and then cache that hash as the key, and the entire result set as the value.

But this feels like a bit of a naive approach given the key-value nature of Redis, and the fact that one entity might be contained within multiple result sets under multiple query hashes.

*(For reference, the source of this data is currently SQL Azure, we're using Azure's hosted Redis service. We're also looking at alternative approaches to hitting the DB incl. denormalizing the data, ETLing the data to CosmosDB, hosting the data in Azure Search but there's other implications for doing these including Implementation time, "freshness" of data etc...)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't try and cache the results, just the individual entities.  When I've done things like this in the past, I return a list of IDs from live queries, and retrieve individual entities from my cache layer.  That way the ID list is always "fresh", and you don't have nasty cache invalidation logic issues.

If you really do have commonly reoccurring searches, you can cache the results (of ids), but you will likely run into issues of pagination and such.  Caching query results can be tricky, as you generally need to cache *all* the results, not just the first "page" worth.  This is generally very expensive, and has high transfer costs that exceed the value of the caching.

Additionally, you will absolutely have freshness issues with caching query results.  As new records show up, they won't be in the cached list.  This is avoided with the entity-only cache, as the list of IDs is always fresh, just the entities themselves can be stale (but that has a much easier cache-expiration methodology).

If you are worried about the staleness of the entities, you can return not only an ID, but also a "Last updated date", which allows you to compare the freshness of each entity to the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the input Rob. There were a couple of other things that hadn't occurred to me when I wrote the original above. 1, using Cosmos is going to be orders of magnitude faster that SQL if we get our denormalization and partition strategy correct. 2. this API can very easily be put behind an Azure API Management Service, which would allow us to do request/response caching. Given both those facts, I think I'll take your advice and scrap the Redis approach. cheers.